Is it necessary to specialize the actor representing the registered user in customer/seller actor?
I am writing the requirements analysis document for my software engineering project. The project consists in the creation of a sales platform where the user must necessarily be registered and plays both the role of customer and seller.
In defining the actors I would like to understand if it makes sense to create an abstract registered user actor as a generalization of customer / seller.
Like this:
 .
Or should I specialize registered user in two different actors Customer and Seller.

Use cases (UC) are in principle related to the goals of the actors, and using generalisation/specialisation can significantly increase the expressivity of your diagram.
If it's all the same, i.e. sellers and customers participate in the same use cases, have almost identical needs, and will use the system in the same way,  keep it as general as possible:

However, usually on a marketplace system, sellers and customers have different goals despite some commonalities:

selling requires to describe items to be sold, and either fix the price or accept a bid;
buying requires seeing/searching what is available, etc.
both may be interested in viewing their transaction history or presenting themselves on the market.

Introducing specialisation can then help, even with very general use-cases to remind these differences and better convey the design that is considered:

Conclusion:

If you feel there's really no difference, keep the actor as general as possible.

But especially in the analysis, and user-centric design, it is useful to be aware of different roles and needs .

If you introduce a specialisation, use a generalisation set to be more specific. sSow "seller" and "customer" as separate actors both specialising "user".  You can then be much more expressive (although this is subjective), and better visualise use cases relevant for:

both actors separately (association with the general actor),
for one or the other actor (association with only seller or only buyer),
or for both actors with different roles (eg. auction needs one seller and several customers).



Here an hypothetical refinement, where distinguishing seller and customer helped to fine-tune the analysis:

CAUTION:  If you create the general abstract actor only for a login or logout, stop and take a deep breath. Login / logout and similarly detailed actions are not use-cases, and are better visualised in activity diagrams that detail the flow of actions of a UC.

So basically, you suggest to create 3 different actor specializations, i.e. Customer, Seller, Customer/Seller. Each actor with its own use cases, then I associate the use cases that apply to both with this Customer/ Seller third actor? May it be a solution?

What I try to suggest is that either one is sufficient (label it "user", "business user" if you want to distinguish from admins, "customer/seller",  or any other generic term) or you need to go to specialisation (but then do not specialise the generic into "customer/seller" but go for a generalisation set with "customer" and "seller".  Even if you'd have only one UC "make an auction", connecting it with seller and customer  immediately conveys the fact that more than one party is involved and their might be different needs. The advantage of this approach is that you would associate a UC ...

... with the generic if it is the same for the two parties, the UC with either customer or seller if it is relevant for only one side, the UC with both only if the two parties are involved. This approach helps to disambiguate more the diagram and allows to more efficiently convey the purpose.

I have edited to better highlight these elements in the answer.

Ok,thanks now I have clarified the doubts about that. Using the same user interface led me to make the choice of  using a unique actor playing both roles.

@Fabio great! Meanwhile I've added some more visual explanations that were more difficult to provide on asmall phone ;-)

I want to thank you very much for the time and effort made for answering my question. I really appreciate that. I don't know how to thank you mate!

@Fabio thank you for this nice feed back. You made my day :-).  If you liked the answer, just upvote it, and if it helped to take the right decision, just accept it with the green checkmark, so that other readers see that despite the length it can help them ;-)

You made my day,too! However, I've accepted your answer. Thanks so much again!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Start writing your use cases or user stories. If the stories diverge between these types of users, it makes sense to clearly separate them. If the stories are the same or only have minimal differences, it may not be useful to split them up.
You don't want to create a new actor for every corner case.
